# VBA code - Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: vba

I'm pretty new at writing VBA code. Trying to write a simple NPV function to calculate the NPV of 8 cash flows with initial investment. Keep getting the "compile error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" message, and not sure how to fix it or what it means. Below is the code i'm trying to write:

```
Sub npv()`
Dim discrate As Double
Dim cashflows(0 To 8) As Double
Dim npval As Double
discrate = 0.1
cashflows(0) = -8000
cashflows(1) = -1000
cashflows(2) = -500
cashflows(3) = 2800
cashflows(4) = 3000
cashflows(5) = 3500
cashflows(6) = 3000
cashflows(7) = 2700
cashflows(8) = 3000
npval = npv(discrate, cashflows)
End Sub
```

Comment: *Trying to write a simple NPV function* - then you need a `Function`, not a `Sub`. You're getting that error because `npv` is parameterless, and you're calling it (recursively???) in that last line by passing two arguments. I'd love to help you fix it, but I've no idea what you're trying to do or what your return value should be.

Comment: I **suspect** that it is meant to be `Function npv() As Double` as the declaration and `npv = Application.NPV(discrate, cashflows)` to set the return value.  (But if it is intended to use this as a UDF, the use of an Excel function name for the name of your own function is really going to confuse things.)

Answer (score 0):

That procedure referred to itself, so that's why it error. You should call the WorksheetFunctions.NPV function